# Is it possible to load AppMaker DropDowns with an Option Text and and Value?

Tags: google-app-maker

I've been able to set the options on an AppMaker DropDown by doing this sort of thing:

```
google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(oA){app.pages.Notes.descendants.Dropdown1.options=oA;})
    .getSelectOptions();//oA is just an array
```

But I'd like to know how to do load different values in the options and value like we can do it in javascript with something like this:

```
 function updateSelect(vA){
      var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i].option,vA[i].value);
      }
    }
```

And I tried this by trying to get a hold of the dom element as follows:

```
var elem=app.pages.myPage.descendants.myDropDown.getElement();
elem.options.length=0;//always gives me an error because options doesn't seem to exist in that object.
```

So for now I've been using the standard HTML dom elements in an AppMaker Html widget and that works okay as long as your select is on the first page.  If it's not on the first page I have found that the onChange event can't load Widgets on pages that are not visible.  It is interesting to note however that you can change the contents of HTML widgets even if they are on other non visible pages.

Anyway the simple question is how can one load one thing into value and another thing into option text in an AppMaker DropDown Widget?

```
<option value="value">text</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a predefined array for your options and values you could do the following for your onAttach Event of your dropdown:

```
var options = ['one thing','two thing','three thing'];
var names = ['another one thing','another two thing','another three thing'];
widget.options = options;
widget.names = names;
```

In this case the values that would get recorded would be the options array, but the items that would be displayed would be from the names array. Hope this gets you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't how I missed that.  It was right on the property editor.